# TemplateDoesNotExist Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy modificando una aplicación en Django de una empresa, la idea es implementar un login como pagina principal, pero me dice que el template no existe, y no encuentro el error, segun yo deberia funcionar.
Alguien sabe cual es el error?

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^$', include('login.urls', namespace='login')),
]
```

settings.py

```
  TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
    }]
INSTALLED_APPS = ['login',
]
```

urls.py (login)

```
from login.views import index

app_name = 'login'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index , name='index'),
]
```

views

```
def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        messages.success(request, 'Error al iniciar sesion')

    return render(request,'login/index.html')
```

estructura

```
APP
|-login
|-|-templates
|-|-|-index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La ubicación de la plantilla que llamas no coincide con la ubicación de dicha plantilla.

**Línea en la Views:**

> return render(request,'**login/index.html**')

**Estructura actual:**

```
APP
|-login
|-|-templates
|-|-|-index.html
```

**Estructura correcta:**

```
APP
|-login
|-|-templates
|-|-|-login
|-|-|-|-index.html
```